# Merge dependency injection by init and load views from nib

Tags: ios, uiview, dependency-injection

To unit test my code I allways use dependency injection by inits like `initWithDependency:(DependencyType *)dependency`, that works fine for most of the situations, this way during unit test I can inject mocked dependencies to my sut.

The problem comes with views, I have some dependencies to inject to views, like formaters and classes I use to apply styles to my UI components. Some of this views are created from a nib. the thing is that I want to create the views injecting them my dependencies.

So my question is, it's a way to do that? I was wondering that I can inject an NSCoder to my initializer and calling super initWithCoder: function this would create my view, how I can create the NSCoder from a nib?